# How to select HTML elements in a Web Browser using .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, html

For the Screen Scraper I'm working on ([Screen Scraper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474991/screen-scraping-web-scraping-web-harvesting-web-data-extraction-etc-using-c)) I would like to be able to select HTML elements on the Web Browser. Do you know if this is possible in .NET 3.5 and if so how do you think you could do it?

Example of what I'm trying to do:

[Visual Web Ripper](http://www.visualwebripper.com/Demonstrations/IntroductionVideo.aspx)

Somehow the program incorporates a web browser and allows the user to click on every HTML element...

Comment: You can use Selenium to do something like that (automation part in video)

Answer (score 0):

The [Fizzler library](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/wiki/ProjectDescription) is pretty good. It uses the HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at it. Basically, I'm trying to do something similar to the new firefox inspect element feature.  http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2szdem1NWdw/TzViXaY4vMI/AAAAAAAAAZQ/aS_3okoJN0k/s1600/nativeFFInspectEl.png

Comment: I've been trying to get VisualFizzler to work for the last hour but no luck.. It compiles but when I try to open a file I get: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. [STAThread] is above Main(), so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I still cant get Visual Fizzler to work properly... If you have a minute here is the [Fizzler](http://www.mediafire.com/?jdt6k7twq3jzdzb) source code.