# Babylon 3d app is not working in WPF web browser control

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, babylonjs

For last 2 weeks we were developing a 3d application using Babylon js. When we tried to embed this app inside a WPF application using the WebBrowser control, we were not able to move the 3d object. We tried Chromium browser as well and there it was working fine but it was slow. Can anyone help me to get the solution?

Comment: not sure but this might be a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287619/webbrowser-how-to-automatically-allow-activex-content

Comment: I understand that English is not your native language but please next time put at least *some* effort into trying to type correctly. I mean, the first 2 words of your title were *Baby loan*..

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: @stijn Thanks for the edit. It was a typing mistake please excuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because WPF uses a IE based WebView which does not support WebGL