# Wait for URL in WebBrowser to load C#

Tags: browser, c#, wait

I'm working on a program that automatically re-posts Craigslist posts in a batch form.

I'm executing a method called `arrayTest()` that contains a line `webBrowser1.Navigate(urls[i]);`. This will get a URL from an Array and have the `webBrowser1` open it. After that is executed, the `clickRepost();` method is called. This method simulates a button click. But the method executes before the `webBrowser1` gets to finish opening the URL.

What i need help on is telling the program to wait for the `webBrowser1` to finish opening the URL before moving on to the next method.

What i have tried so far:

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => {
    webBrowser1.Navigate(urls[i]);
})
t.wait();
clickRepost();
```

This still causes for `clickRepost()` to not let `webBrowser1` finish loading the URL. I also tried to add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)` in between calling methods but as it does so in Java, it only shuts the program for x-Seconds.

This is a segment of my program, really the only ones I'm having trouble with.

```
private void arrayTest()
    {
        String[] urls = CLLinks.Text.Split('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.Length; i++)
        {
            log.AppendText("Opening Url...\n");
            webBrowser1.Navigate(urls[i]);
            log.AppendText("Reposting...\n");
            clickRepost();
            log.AppendText("Checking Completion...");
            webBrowser1.Navigate(urls[i]);
            completionCheck();
        }
    }

    private void CLRenBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        arrayTest();
    }

    private void completionCheck()
    {
        HtmlElementCollection col = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        foreach (HtmlElement item in col)
        {
            if (!(item.GetAttribute("value") == "Renew this Posting"))
            {
                log.AppendText("Renew Posting does not exist");
            }
            else
            { }
        }
    }

    private void clickRepost()
    {
        HtmlElementCollection col = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        foreach (HtmlElement item in col)
        {
            if (item.GetAttribute("value") == "Renew this Posting")
            {
                item.InvokeMember("click");
            }
            else
            {}
        }
    }
```

`CLRenBtn_Click` Is the button i press on the form to start the Re-posting. `arrayTest()` will be changed to a more relevant name. At the time i was just testing whether this would work. And im planning on merging `clickRepost()` and `completionCheck()` since they do the same thing.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Next time post programming questions on Stack Overflow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer!
[C# how to wait for a webpage to finish loading before continuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583897/c-sharp-how-to-wait-for-a-webpage-to-finish-loading-before-continuing)

Worked good for me, but now my little problem is that, when i start the reposting. it skips the first url in the array and posts the ones that follow.