# C# Foreach goes too quickly for the webbrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am coding in C# using WindowsForms.
I am trying to iterate through a list of ID's that changes the url of a webbrowser control.

ClientID is an  `List<int> ClientID = new List<int>();`
And filled with around 10-15 different numbers.

The foreach goes too quickly for the webbrowser control, and because of that the ErrorDiv is always null. The site isn't able to load, thus I am not able to check for the div with the specified class. If this class does exist, the foreach has to contiue with the next Client.

```
 foreach (int Client in ClientID)
        {
          
            if(webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate(URLconsult + "/" + Client);
            }
           
           

            var ErrorDiv = webBrowser1.Document
            .GetElementsByTagName("div")
            .Cast<HtmlElement>()
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetAttribute("className") == "incompleteConsultNotification");

            Console.WriteLine(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div").Cast<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetAttribute("className") == "incompleteConsultNotification"));
            

           
            //if (ErrorDiv == null)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Normal");
            //}
            //else
            //{

            //    Error.Add(Client);
            //    continue;
            //}

        }
```

**The HTML div I try to target:**

```
 <div class="incompleteConsultNotification">
            This form is incomplete. Please add the following:
            <ul>
                                        <li> option 1</li>
                                        <li> option 2</li>
                                </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Surely after the Navigate command you need to check ReadyState again before continuing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/583909/5947043 seems to show a more reliable / efficient way to wait, using an event handler

Comment: Oh thanks you both, Fixed it with an while loop after wb.navigate